# Need help writing a regex which matches every string against a given format

Tags: java, regex

Can someone please help me writing a regex which matches every string against below format.

```
format : @<AnyString>,T<digits>
```

e.g. @Bob,T20

Comment: What have you tried/researched? It looks like most of the regex you need is given to you, just go research the missing parts.

Comment: can you share more information for  `AnyString`? is it contains `,T` or `@` too?

Comment: Are you facing any specific difficulty while writing such regex? Can you [edit] your question and include your best attempt along with description of problem in it?

Comment: `^@.+,T\d+$` technically fits the requirement you've presented.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**For format validation:**

Try:
`^@[a-zA-Z]*,T\d*$`

If you need at least 1 string and 1 digit:
`^@[a-zA-Z]+,T\d+$`

**For match in text:**

Try: `@[a-zA-Z]*,T\d*`

If you need at least 1 string and 1 digit: `@[a-zA-Z]+,T\d+`

Comment: What if `@Bob,T20` is in the middle of a line of text?

Comment: Thanks @Bob, "@[a-zA-Z]*,T\d*" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`@([a-zA-Z]+),T([0-9]+)`

If `<AnyString>` is comprised only of letters in the case of your example. If you want it to check for digits or other characters, simply add `0-9` or the given characters to the square brackets in the first capture group. Or

`@(.+),T([0-9]+)`

if it should match a string comprised of any character.

Consider having a look at [regexr](https://regexr.com/) for these issues. It is a very helpful tool when creating regular expressions.

Comment: @JonnyHenly you are right, I always seem to forget about `+`. I've updated my answer. Thanks.